# How to solve the lldb error in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios7, crash, lldb

My app works fine on simulator, and worked on the device, but once upon a time it started to crash.
I just get "lldb" error with no messages. When I type "bt" command I see this:

> - thread #1: tid = 0x24a8, 0x38a1fcc0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
>     frame #0: 0x38a1fcc0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
>     frame #1: 0x2e284bd0 CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise] + 8
>     frame #2: 0x2ebca15e Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 202
>     frame #3: 0x2ebdbd8c Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 300
>     frame #4: 0x2e1f4a54 CoreFoundation`-[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 180
>     frame #5: 0x30e2553e UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1122
>     frame #6: 0x30d7de8e UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 234
>     frame #7: 0x30bda344 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadView] + 92
>     frame #8: 0x30aba874 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 72
>     frame #9: 0x30aba7f0 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 24
>     frame #10: 0x30bda276 UIKit`-[UIWindow handleStatusBarChangeFromHeight:toHeight:] + 694
>     frame #11: 0x30b41416 UIKit`+[UIWindow _noteStatusBarHeightChanged:oldHeight:forAutolayoutRootViewsOnly:] + 238
>     frame #12: 0x30c41b10 UIKit__79 - [UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:]_block_invoke + 132
>     frame #13: 0x30aeba1a UIKit`+[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 490
>     frame #14: 0x30c2431e UIKit`+[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:completion:] + 70
>     frame #15: 0x30b66dca UIKit`-[UIApplication _setStatusBarHidden:animationParameters:changeApplicationFlag:] + 462
>     frame #16: 0x30ac18e0 UIKit`-[UIApplication _updateCurrentStatusBarViewControllerAppearance] + 248
>     frame #17: 0x30abed72 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 234
>     frame #18: 0x30b28a30 UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 60
>     frame #19: 0x30b256c4 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1820
>     frame #20: 0x30b1fca8 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 720
>     frame #21: 0x30abbc76 UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3550
>     frame #22: 0x30abadd8 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
>     frame #23: 0x30b1f3e4 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 616
>     frame #24: 0x33128b54 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 608
>     frame #25: 0x3312873e GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 34
>     frame #26: 0x2e24f806 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
>     frame #27: 0x2e24f7a2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
>     frame #28: 0x2e24df6e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1406
>     frame #29: 0x2e1b8728 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
>     frame #30: 0x2e1b850a CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
>     frame #31: 0x30b1e60a UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 762
>     frame #32: 0x30b19870 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
>     <ul>
>     <li>frame #33: 0x000e5ed8 SpriteKitSimpleGame`main(argc=1, argv=0x27d62c34) + 116 at main.m:16

I can't understand why it crashes. What may be the reason?

## **UPD**

I've disabled Exception Breakpoints and got the new strange error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key snewRecordLabel.'

The **snewRecordLabel** is deleted from the Storyboard UILabel, but it probably is the reason of error. How to remove it?

Comment: Do you have Exception Breakpoints enabled?

Comment: @latenitecoder Yes, I do.

Comment: Type `thread continue` in the `lldb` console and the exception will make itself known (it will be about key-value coding by the look of it).

Answer (score 0):

There is some connection is in storyboard for snewRecordLabel, you can open storyboard into simple textedit & see xml data if you find snewRecordLabel, than there must be missing link will be present in storyboard.